# A10-5750M clock-lock FPS drop

Tags: overclocking, lag

Why does this happen?

i have the A10-5750m and running on Windows 8.1.

i used bar-edit to clock-lock the A10-5750m up to 3.2ghz (the max turbo boost is 3.5ghz)..

( Tutorial here >http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpYK9Gnzj9I ) *that is not me btw

It is ok when running normal applications such as firefox , and steam.. But when i fire up a game such as CSGO or ArcheAge , i will have great lags after a few minutes , and the lags will stay for a few seconds and up to a few minutes.. ( FPS Drops until 5 or below... )

Other specs is:

HD8650G(within the 5750M)
HD8570M
8GB DDR3 1333mhz.

*sorry about the grammar..

Comment: What happens if you remove the clock - lock?

Comment: it goes back to the normal clock , 2.5ghz....

and all will be fine...

but i thought that if i clock-lock at 3.2ghz , it should be fine coz its not the max clock-lock(3.5ghz) , and im not even overclocking...

Comment: Then chances are what you are seeing is thermal throttling and you either need to improve your cooling or simply not lock or over clock your processor.

Comment: ah... ok.. hmm... thermal then... i thought 3.2 shouldnt be that hard. but... hmm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably the cpu reaching a thermal limit and then restricting itself for a period of time so that it can cool down  enough to continue working safely.

Heat output does not scale linearly with clock speed, it scales exponentially.  What this means is that a 10% increase in clock speed does not necessarily mean a 10% increase in temperature. At the top end of their limits a 10% clock boost can mean a 50-100% increase in thermal output.

You need to monitor your CPU temperature and make sure it is not getting too high. I've previously used [Coretemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) for this and I would expect it to work fine.

You need to test at various speeds and find out where your system is stable and the temperatures do not get too high, or simply let the CPU manage itself.

Alternatively you may want to look at replacing thermal paste and getting an aftermarket cooler for your processor. Many other coolers perform better than cheap stock coolers and could give you a bit more leeway with overclocking.

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly same processor and I used Bar-Edit. I guess the laptop is MSI GX70 or a similar?

I had the exact same problem with severe FPS drop. Your processor is surely overheating. Since I bought a cooling pad I never experienced this problem (weather was as hot as before I bought the cooling pad).

I suggest to disable PowerNow function in BIOS to prevent throttling - it may improve performance greatly (you will need to use Bar-Edit less often), but battery life will be reduced a lot.